# Mapbox GL JS: Set Map Center or Bounds to show visible part of a layer

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have a layer with 7000+ polygons and am displaying a portion of the polygons in a web app using "setFilter" on map load. (The filter is choosing the polygons to display dynamically based on data from the url of the current page.)

However, I can't figure out how to make the map center on the particular polygons currently showing (the visible part of that layer), which means the user has to hunt around to find it. There can be multiple polygons visible at one time, and they are a range of different sizes. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [turf.bbox](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bbox) which takes a polygon and returns a bounding box and pass the result to `map.fitBounds(BBOX)` to center the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [feature collection](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects) of polygons that are visible on your map, you can use the [`turf-extent`](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-extent/) module to get the geographical extent of the visible polygons, and then call [`map.fitBounds(extent)`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#fitBounds) to make all visible polygons within the viewport.